# how to update or replace docker layer force

Tags: docker

I am using docker to build an image,when the image running in my kubernetes cluster.I found one script need to change some content.So I change the souce shell script and rebuild the docker image:

```
docker build -t="dabai-fat/soa-revolver-service:v1.0.0" .
```

but when I am push the image to remote registry:

```
docker push registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/soa-revolver:v1.0.0
```

It shows reuse the old layer,so what would I do to force update. This is the log detail output:

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Document/source/dabai/microservice/soa-revolver on  develop! ⌚ 16:06:32
$ ./script/docker-deploy-impl.sh
+ /usr/bin/expect
spawn sudo docker login --username=loginusername registry.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com
Password:
Password:
Login Succeeded
+ docker tag dabai-fat/soa-revolver-service:v1.0.0 registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/soa-revolver:v1.0.0
+ docker push registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/soa-revolver:v1.0.0
The push refers to repository [registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/soa-revolver]
84e92d15b774: Layer already exists
0d30d3e39916: Layer already exists
edd61588d126: Layer already exists
9b9b7f3d56a0: Layer already exists
f1b5933fe4b5: Layer already exists
v1.0.0: digest: sha256:7179cd8e6b0a39c39211d1b7ba5784b9c645b07bd59e479037f55345b1f14d04 size: 1366
```

Comment: You would see this behavior if the new image is identical to an old one.  Did the `docker build` actually succeed?  If you try to `docker run` the built image locally, do you actually see your change?